# how to display my content on a html page in android

Tags: android, html

I want to display my data's in a html page, I make a static html page in assest folder .but don't know how to insert my data's in that html page programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading an html page from an asset is relatively simple:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

But to programatically alter the content of the page you'd have to first read the asset file into a string, insert your data with a string replace, or use java.text.MessageFormat.

Here's the code to get an inputstream from an asset:

```
AssetManager mgr = this.getAssets();
InputStream is = mgr.open("index.html");
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(is);
// read the contents of the file
```

Once you have your html string populated, you can programmatically set the content of the webview:

```
webView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) in your activity. Then load the html into the webview, here are some [instructions](http://www.help4android.com/2010/06/how-to-easily-access-included-files-in.html).